# In C# can I use a List key as a argument in a method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a method in C# to let me equip a item or level it up if acquired.

My current code for the scriptable objects has each item having 2 things a itemclass and a itemLevel.

So whiplevel1 would have itemClass whip and itemLevel 1.

And if I already had whiplevel1 and was running this again I'd expect either other weapons or whiplevel 2 but never whiplevel1 again.

I have made many iterations of this code over and over trying to get this to work.

this is a small example

```
public class Database : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ItemDatabase items;
    private static Database instance;
    private static int Whip = 0;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }


    public static Item GetChooseableItemByItemLevel(string itemClass,int itemLevel)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i >= instance.items.allItems.Count; i++)
        {
            if (instance.items.allItems[i].itemLevel == itemLevel && instance.items.allItems[i].itemClass == itemClass)
            {
                
                Database.itemClass += 1;
                return instance.items.allItems[i];
                
            }
            
        }
        return null;
    }
```

If using Database.itemClass worked I'd be golden and could do the rest but I don't know how to do that in C#

Comment: Have you tried compiling your code? Does it allow you to? What are you trying to actually reference with `Database.itemClass`? It seems like that should be a property on your `Database` class.

Comment: What is a value of `Database.ItemClass` isn't that a string? Aldo, you're not modifying `instance.items.allItems[i];` at all with the new values. You need to change those variables don't you?. You're code is a little incomplete at this point we're making assumptions.  If ItemClass is a string why are you using +=1 shoudn't it be ItemLevel += 1?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to access a property `itemClass` that doesn't exist on your `Database` class. You do access an `itemClass` property in your `if` statement though.

Perhaps replacing

```
Database.itemClass += 1;
```

with

```
instance.items.allItems[i].itemClass += 1;
```

would help?

Then you are actually using your current `instance` of the `Database` class, and able to access the `items` `ItemDatabase` from it.

The way you tried to do it using `Database.itemClass` would only work if you had `itemClass` statically defined in the `Database` class. You need an actual instance of the `Database` class to access your `ItemDatabase`. (See Microsoft's documentation on static classes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members))

Comment: Im sorry for the Vagueness of my code but what i was actually trying to acomplish there was using the string value of allItems[i].itemClass as a way to point towards Database.Whip.

So in that instance allItems[i].itemClass is a string varible called whip and i have a entry on my database.cs called DataBase.Whip = 0; so that if an item is chosen it would update the database entry a level. 

im new to C# so the syntax is all over the place.

Right now im trying the same thing all over again but using a dictionary thats items that are obtained to compare the key value pairs to possible.

Comment: Perhaps posting the rest of your code would help. What is `ItemDatabase`? There is no way to tell what is actually happening in that class or how you are accessing it because you have other syntax issues. For all we know, `ItemDatabase` doesn't even exist and you just typed it there (just like `Database.itemClass`).  This is why I originally commented asking if it even compiles. There are a lot of questionable things in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i >= instance.items.allItems.Count; i++)
```

This is the problem, that loop will only execute (infinitely) if you have 0 items on list, should be probably:

```
for(int i = 0; i < instance.items.allItems.Count; i++)
```

Comment: That was one of the many problems with my method thank you